# Slicing n elements with stride m from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I want to find a concise way to sample n consecutive elements with stride m from a numpy array. The simplest case is with sampling 1 element with stride 2, which means getting every other element in a list, which can be done like this:

```
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> a[::2]
array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
```

However, what if I wanted to slice n consecutive elements with a stride of m where n and m can be any integers? For example, if I wanted to slice 2 consecutive elements with a stride of 3 I would get something like this:

```
array([0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9])
```

Is there a pythonic and concise way of doing this? Thank you!

Comment: So, the final array could be longer when the intervals overlap `array([0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4...])`? Should the approach be able to handle negative inputs?

Comment: `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, (4,2), (8*3, 8)).ravel()[:-1]` will give you it, but there might be a cleaner way to do it that does not involve reading one int64 outside the allocated memory.

Comment: @Mr.T Yes, and it should be able to handle any input. It should do a slicing operation, therefore simply creating a new view without copying it in memory anywhere...

Comment: @Kevin I guess that's a workaround, but I should change the input shape and stride every time which makes it quite inconvenient... Maybe there doesn't exit an elegant way to do it with simple python slicing

Comment: I am no numpy expert but how can a view of an array be longer than the array itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `a` is long enough you could reshape, slice, and ravel

```
a.reshape(-1,3)[:,:2].ravel()
```

But `a` has to be (9,) or (12,).  And the result will still be a copy.

The suggested:

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, (4,2), (8*3, 8)).ravel()[:-1]
```

is also a copy.  The `as_strided` part is a view, but `ravel` will make a copy.  And there is the ugliness of that extra element.

`sliding_window_view` was added as a safer version:

```
In [81]: np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(a,(3))
Out[81]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [5, 6, 7],
       [6, 7, 8],
       [7, 8, 9]])
In [82]: np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(a,(3))[::3,:2]
Out[82]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4],
       [6, 7]])
```

Again `ravel` will make a copy.  This omits the "extra" `9`.

`np.resize` does a `reshape` with padding (repeating `a` as needed):

```
In [83]: np.resize(a, (4,3))
Out[83]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8],
       [9, 0, 1]])
In [84]: np.resize(a, (4,3))[:,:2]
Out[84]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4],
       [6, 7],
       [9, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This code might be useful, I tested it on the example in the question (n=2, m=3)

```
import numpy as np

def get_slice(arr, n, m):
    b = np.array([])
    for i in range(0, len(arr), m):
        b = np.concatenate((b, arr[i:i + n]))
    return b

sliced_arr = get_slice(np.arange(10), n=2, m=3)
print(sliced_arr)
```

Output

```
[0. 1. 3. 4. 6. 7. 9.]
```

Comment: This kind of works but with concatenate it creates a new copy which makes it quite slow...

Comment: Your desired result has to to be a copy.  The 'slicing' isn't regular enough to be a view.